# missing required keys: [:id] for a link to edit in parents view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I attempt to run my code, I got the error above. 
Here's my giftcards_controller.rb :

```
def edit 
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @giftcard = @order.giftcard.where(giftcard_id params[:id])
end
```

Here's my order/new.html.erb view :

```
<%= link_to edit_order_giftcard_path(@order), data: { modal: true } do %>
  <p>Edit card</p>
<% end %>
```

the routes.rb file :

```
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update, :edit] do
    resources :giftcards, except: [:index, :show]
end
```

and the error :

```
(No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"giftcards", :id=>nil, :order_id=>#<Order id: 1, subtotal: #<BigDecimal:7fa963be4330,'0.3E1',9(18)>, tax: nil, shipping: nil, total: nil, created_at: "2015-12-11 09:00:30", updated_at: "2015-12-11 09:00:30", guid: "gaavqd", stripe_id: nil, email: nil, billing_address_id: nil, shipping_address_id: nil, bill_to_shipping_address: false, giftcard_id: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

how could I pass the id ?

Answer (score 1):

In the error you showed, it seems that you are passing an Object and you want it to just pass the id. You can do it with:

`<%= link_to edit_order_giftcard_path(@order.id), data: { modal: true } do %>`

Comment: Thanks, I did it with "@giftcard = @order.giftcard(params[:id])" in the controller and "link_to edit_order_giftcard_path(@order.id, :giftcard)" in my view

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're passing `id`'s for *both* elements of the [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

When you have the following:

```
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update, :edit] do
   resources :giftcards, except: [:index, :show]
end
```

... it means that `giftcards` will be available *if* you have an `order` defined too.

Thus, you'll want to make sure you set up your link as follows:

```
<%= link_to edit_order_giftcard_path(@order, @giftcard) ... %>
```

---

Another important factor to understand the difference between [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) and [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find):

```
@giftcard = @order.giftcard.where(giftcard_id params[:id])
```

This is **not** valid code.

Firstly, you're using `where`, which pulls multiple elements (which will not work in your `link_to`). Secondly, it's referencing `giftcard` when I believe you'd need `giftcards`...

You need the following:

```
def edit 
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @giftcard = @order.giftcards.find params[:id]
end
```

Comment: Thank you , I knew my controller sucks , I do not know why I dared published in the state.